# 3D Terrain Model collision

Tags: opengl, model, 3d, collision, terrain

So after trying to implement heighmap terrain loading into my 3D game environment and failing, I kind of cheated and loaded my terrain into my 3D game using models from blender instead as OBJ files. I kind of realized that this will be expensive and will probably bite me in the ass later, but at that time I didn't really care.

So now, I'm at a point where I have to implement terrain and model collision. Normally if I loaded my terrain with height maps it would be easy, but now I'm at a loss as to how to implement terrain model collision, since both are techinally meshes.

Generally, meshses loaded from OBJ files would use bounding box or sphere collision to detect model-to-model collision. But in my case, the terrain mesh is humongous, and other models(tanks, humans, trees....) lie on top of my terrain mesh. So none of those methods work.

Another attempt from me was to directly retrieve all 80000 vertices data from my terrain OBJ file, compare those vertices data with the data from my other models.But the problem with that is that it is extremely unefficient and expensive, due to the fact that I must check all 80000 vertices every render cycle, causing massive FPS drop rates and rendering the game unplayable.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to implement terrain-models collision, when both model and terrain are loaded from OBJ files and are meshes? Or is it that I just have to go back to loading terrain from height maps?

Comment: Have you tried to generate a heightmap from the mesh (after you load the mesh from the obj)?

Answer (score 1):

Triangle soup collision detection has been thoroughly researched, there are several publications and books on it (e.g. http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/). And most importantly there are quite efficient open source libraries doing the job for you. A popular choice among physics engine developers seems to be [OPCODE](http://www.codercorner.com/Opcode.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I have some problems with loading OPCODE libraries and other libraries. It's generally really annoying and hard for me to load other libraries into my project. Otherthan OPCODE, RAPID and libraries like that, is there any other more well known and documented library for collision?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a heightmap for your terrain you can still use it to compute collisions. There's no problem using triangle mesh for rendering and height map for collisions at the same time.

Comment: That's the problem. The terrain is really a model made from blender. I only have texture files and an OBJ file for the terrain. No heighmaps. The OBJ files only have vertices that are triangulated. I kind of have to go through all vertices for all the triangles, and somehow do collision detection using those vertices

Comment: If your terrain doesn't have caves etc. then you can bake the heightmap from your mesh. I'm not sure how to do this in Blender but it's possible. This solution will be much faster than any mesh-based one.

Comment: Except its a desert with caves, pillars...... And the vertices are triangulated mesh. Although it definitely could be an idea to make a height map from the OBJ file

Comment: Come to think of it, is there any tool (such as Blender), that can create a bmp height map, from an OBJ file? Most tools like Blender creates a 3d Model from bmp files, what about the other way around?

Comment: Try this: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Textures/Maps/Creating_a_Heightmap_from_a_Plane